# What is the best way to track unique and overall clicks at my newsletters

Tags: 7, emails, google-analytics

I send newsletters from my Drupal-7 website and I want to track how many times the links where clicked and how many unique click events I had.

I use [Simplenews module](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) and I use some basic GA utm parameters, but the results I get are not satisfying. What do you suggest I use. Is there a method, or a way to get that? Everywhere I search there is not a valid answer to my question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you familiar with the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en as it will help you build a link you can put in your newsletter that when clicked takes the person to whatever page you direct them to, but has analytic code built into the link so that you can track how many and how often it is used. Total sessions and unique users will both be tracked.